# Strange askubuntu edit post behaviour

Tags: support

In the course of trying to edit a post that had *its edit button* active *not greyed out* I experienced something strange.

When I clicked on the *edit* button (which as stated above was not greyed out) this happened,

```
I was taken to a blank new page with the notice " There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes"
```

Now usually:

- I would see the *edit* button *greyed out* if the above case were so.
- I won't be taken to a separate page on clicking on edit, it would simply present its *message via a pop-up window as I try to access edit*

Here is an image of the page I was directed to:

[image]

**NOTE:** was accessing the site from *Kubuntu 16.04 guest OS in Ubuntu 16.04 host*